# I need help understanding the concept of norms

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

I’ve been looking everywhere to really grasp what a norm is. Any clarification would be helpful and maybe some drawings and examples would help too!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: A very basic description of what a norm is, considering the absolute value is the simplest example, is that as the length of a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ on a vector space $(V, \mathbb{F}, +, \boldsymbol{0}, \cdot)$ is a function from $\lVert \cdot \rVert \colon V \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ that gives a notion of 'size' to the vector space. It is a generalization of the absolute value $\lvert \cdot \rvert$ of a real number to general vector spaces. A vector space equipped with a norm is a normed vector space.

A norm must obey certain properties:

1. For any $\boldsymbol{v} \in V$, $\lVert \boldsymbol{v}\rVert = 0$ if and only if $\boldsymbol{v} = \boldsymbol{0}$. (Nondegeneracy)
2. For any $\boldsymbol{v} \in V$, and any $a \in \mathbb{F}$, $\lVert a \boldsymbol{v} \rVert = \lvert a \rvert\, \lVert \boldsymbol{v} \rVert$. (Scalar multiplicativity)
3. For any $\boldsymbol{v}, \boldsymbol{u} \in V$, $\lVert \boldsymbol{v} + \boldsymbol{u} \rVert \le \lVert \boldsymbol{v} \rVert + \lVert \boldsymbol{u} \rVert$. (Triangle inequality)

From these properties, we can also derive that no vector may have a negative norm.

Taking $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, we see that the absolute value satisfies the norm properties. Similarly, taking $\mathbb{C}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, the modulus $\lvert a + bi\rvert := \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ satisfies the norm properties.

For a vector space $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}, +, \boldsymbol{0}, \cdot)$, the most basic norm is the *Euclidean norm*. The Euclidean norm, denoted $\lVert\cdot\rVert_2\,$ (for reasons which will become clear shortly), of a vector $\boldsymbol{x} = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined as

$$\lVert \boldsymbol{x} \rVert_2 := \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n{{x_i}^2}}$$

This is the normal notion of distance from the origin in (Euclidean) Cartesian space, as given by Pythagoras' Theorem.

Another common norm is the *taxicab* or *Manhattan* norm, denoted $\lVert\cdot\rVert_1$. The taxicab norm of a vector $\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined as

$$\lVert \boldsymbol{x} \rVert_1 := \sum_{i=1}^n{\lvert x_i \rvert}$$

This can be understood as the distance from the origin, if one can only move along the axes of the space.

These two naturalistic norms can be generalized to the $p$-norms, denoted $\lVert\cdot\rVert_p$. The $p$-norm of a vector $\boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, for real $p$ such that $p \ge 1$, is defined as

$$\lVert \boldsymbol{x} \rVert_p := \left(\sum_{i=1}^n{\lvert x_i \rvert^p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$

Finally, taking the limit as $p$ goes to infinity, we obtain the $\infty$-norm, also known as the *Chebyshëv* or *chess* norm.

$$\Vert \boldsymbol{x} \rVert_\infty := \lim_{p \to \infty}{\lVert \boldsymbol{x} \rVert_p} = \max{(\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\})}$$

This can be understood as the maximum distance along any axis of the space.

These norms generalize easily to finite-dimensional vector spaces.

They can also be generalized to countably infinite vector spaces (sequence spaces), where the sum converges. The normed subspaces $\ell^p \subset \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ (where $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is the vector space of sequences with elements in $\mathbb{R}$ under componentwise addition and scalar multiplication) consist of all sequences in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ for which the $p$-norm is defined.

To generalize these to the function space $F$ of functions $f \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ where $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, we define

$$\lVert f \rVert_p := \left( \int_X{\lvert f(x) \rvert^p \, \mathrm{d}x} \right)^\frac{1}{p}$$

and

$$\lVert f \rVert_\infty := \sup{(\{\, \lvert f(x) \rvert \mid x \in X \, \})}$$

Any inner product space $(V, \mathbb{F}, +, \boldsymbol{0}, \cdot, \langle \cdot \rangle)$ can be equipped with the norm induced by the inner product, defined by

$$\lVert \boldsymbol{v} \rVert := \sqrt{\langle \boldsymbol{v}, \boldsymbol{v} \rangle}$$

Lastly, any normed vector space $(V, \mathbb{F}, +, \boldsymbol{0}, \cdot, \lVert \cdot \rVert)$ can be equipped with the metric induced by the norm, defined by

$$d(\boldsymbol{v}, \boldsymbol{u}) := \lVert \boldsymbol{v} - \boldsymbol{u} \rVert$$

Thus, all inner product spaces are normed vector spaces, and all normed vector spaces are metric spaces.

Hope that helps!